# About implementing filters on event database website

Tags: javascript, database, wordpress, filter

Good day to you,

I've started my journey with code few weeks ago, currently mastering CSS and slowly proceeding to JS. I understand that the most efficient way to learn is actually through trying to develop your own products.

So I'm going to create website where you can find variety of information about very specific events around the world. Not going into unnecessary details... I need to know what are next skills to acquire to be able to launch such project. The design is such it should be simple landing page with lots of filters such as ticket price, country location, chosen date  (based on information in the code or/and connected directly to Facebook events). The user can also choose to geolocate events via interactive map where all options are visible. The purpose is to show the results to user after filtering the rest of the data out. After this user can click on events that match his requirements and proceed to subpages to gather more specific information.

**How to manage this? Could this be deployed on vanilla JS/jQuery or I will need to also learn some PHP and create some kind of database?** Maybe needed data about the events can be put directly in the lines of code using pure CSS/JS? Also, do you think that launching this one on Wordpress could be helpful taking in mind some helpful plugins or should I build everything from scratch?

Sorry if this question sounds very noobie in style but I'm completely fresh in this and very eager to start project from which I can learn. At the same time need some support about what next language is most critical I need to know to make this happen.

Thanks

Comment: Good day to you too, Marcel. I'm affraid this kind of questions is not suitable for stackoverflow, as recommendation questions are off topic. You'll have to find help about that somewhere else, and throughout your journey to learn, if you ever ancounter any problems or need help about a specific programming thing, SO is the right place to ask about it.

Comment: ... Also, your question may attract some downvotes and get closed, so don't get frustrated by that as it is how SO users instinctively react to off topic questions. Good luck!